# How to split code in library for spring boot starter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-starter

Imagine that I have a **library A**, that provide a given functionality that can be enabled like a spring-boot-starter, meaning that adding the dependency to my project will make it available.

On the other end I have another **library B**, that provide another functionality, similar to library A in the way it works, but it is a totally different feature.

Now I have a case where if the project include **libraries A and B** I would like to configure some bean in a specific way.

My question is how to decide where to do write the code needed both libraries, clearly it should either be:

- library A having optional dependency on B with a specific @Configuration that enable that bean
- the opposite, library B having optional dependency on A with a specific @Configuration that enable that bean

On purpose I leave the name A and B to be as generic as possible in my case, one library is applying some specific configuration for mongo and the other one is to wrap the mongock migration tool.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

1. Write your libraries A and B without Spring Boot in mind (no beans, no dependency injection etc.)
2. Declare both libraries as dependencies (Maven/Gradle) in your project
3. Define a @Configuration class that defines all the beans that you need, similar to [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/creating-bean-definitions.html)
4. Decide with [Spring profiles](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles) and [@Qualifier](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-qualifier-annotation) which been you need when

I wrote a blogpost about how you can use @Profile to decide for different Spring Beans based on the given scenario: https://medium.com/twodigits/keep-your-code-debuggable-4ad69e5e0ac7